# PHP MySQL Update Function not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

**Hello**

I need help with getting this to work, i've tried everything.
it just doesn't seem to do the trick for me..

Please if someone can help me i would appreciate it a lot :)

```
    function ChangeConfig()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit-config']))
        {
                $website_name = $_POST['website_name'];
                $website_sub  = $_POST['website_sub'];
                $data  = "UPDATE config SET website_name = '$website_name', website_sub = '$website_sub' WHERE id = 1";
                $query = mysql_query($data);

                if($query)
                {
                    echo "Success!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo mysql_error();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the mysql error? "It's not working" is **not** an error message.

Comment: what does mysql_error() output?
maybe you should take a look at the new mysqli-extension of php. Also your code seems to wait for SQL-injections...

Comment: Your entire code is dependant on your conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['submit-config']))` - Make sure that the submit button is indeed named and no typos; i.e.: `name="submit-config"`, including all of your other form elements. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. It will most likely will throw you errors. Plus, you are calling the function, right?

Comment: Danger, danger, SQL injection!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you need some concatenation:

```
$data  = "UPDATE `config` SET `website_name` = '".$website_name."', `website_sub` = '".$website_sub."' WHERE id = 1";
```

I would highly recommend using a prepared statement here though by switching from mysql to mysqli. Doing it this way is a security risk and prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Didnt work. Yes i will redo everything later when i learn PDO better :)

Comment: If you want to go the PDO route you can, but in my opinion mysqli is simpler and has much of the same functionality. Take a look here : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

If your `id` field is a `varchar`, try to put quotes `' '` around the value `1`:

```
WHERE id = '1'
```

Another thing you should do is to add the "or die" command at the end of the wuery function, like that:

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())
```

This is very useful to understand the error returned.

Consult the manual on PHP.net:
 -**http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php**

Comment: *"Try to put `''` around the value `1`"* - Only if the column is `varchar`. We don't know that. I always ask questions first, unless the error is apparent, which in this case isn't.

Comment: Nope, thats not the problem here..

Comment: @user3904663 [`Have you read this?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108747/php-mysql-update-function-not-working#comment39074719_25108747)

Comment: Ye, its not giving anything. only notice: undefined index variables. but thats normal.

Comment: *"undefined index variables"* - So, you don't see this as a problem then. @user3904663

Comment: Just tells me i havent defined my vars. It have nothing to do with the problem, cause i already tried defining them and still nothing.